# Cannot use git extension in Brackets

Tags: git, adobe-brackets

I have installed git extension in Brackets and was using couple of weeks ago. i returned to use Brackets this week, but no way to use it to integrate with  github.
I can see the git extension was installed.

I remember I can right click the left panel to choose "Source..." then commit, pull, ... etc. Now that was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bracket editor](http://brackets.io/), with [Git extension](http://brackets.dnbard.com/extension/zaggino.brackets-git) ([`zaggino/brackets-git`](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git)) should be used:

- `git(.exe)` in your PATH.
- within a local git repo (so your files should be in a folder including a .git)
- with a remote set to a GitHub repo (git remote -v should return an https GitHub url)

Double-check "[Brackets & Git Integration](http://rickluna.com/wp/2016/03/brackets-git-integration/) "

Comment: Hi, I was using git to sync my local with GitHub couple of weeks ago, then I switched to VS Code to practice and the git still working inside VS Code.
I checked Extension Manager Brackets Git was installed (Martin Zagora), should I Remove the extension and reinstall it?

Comment: @RickyNelson you can try a reinstall, but only after double-checking your PATH, git.exe and remote url of your local repo.